# Xcode how do I duplicate a View Controller? I've had this complication for days

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

How do I duplicate View Controllers, so I don't have to re-place the menu screen in my UI, because it stays constant throughout each screen.

Somebody told me to copy this:
[image: example]

However 'View Controller Scene' is not in my project navigator...

[image]

So they told me: "You have to right click in your project navigator and create a new file. Select "Cocoa Touch Class" and create a subclass of UIViewController."

I did exactly that, but it gives me code files, not a 'View Controller Scene' in which I can copy the 'View Controller' in order to have two of the same on my storyboard.

I am using Objective C, and I have had this problem for days, can somebody PLEASE help me out?

Comment: Where is the menu going to be located on each screen? Is this like a slide in side menu? Describe a bit more about what the outcome is that you want

Comment: You know how on the storyboard there is a square where you can insert UI elements? I want to duplicate that, so there are two of the same one on the storyboard, which I can then edit seperately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first photo, where you have the "View Controller" highlighted, click on the left arrow to open the view hierarchy. Select the view that comprises your menu and hit Command + D or Edit > Duplicate.

This will create a duplicate version of your menu in the same ViewController. Grab the duplicated copy and move it to any other scene you want in your Storyboard

EDIT: You're looking at the wrong menu. Click on your Main.storyboard and then in the bottom Left of the Storyboard, click the little menu icon that opens the Document Outline. Alternatively, go to Editor > Show Document Outline when Main.storyboard is selected

Comment: That first photo isn't my screen, that's the problem. I don't have that item in my project navigator, look at the second photo, that's all that is there for 'me'

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm a just a UI designer and new to xcode. It's so confusing! Haha, thanks again!!!

Comment: If you spent a long time on that last issue, I highly recommend spending an hour and going through this reference. It sounds like as a UI designer, you'll spend most of your time in Interface Builder for apps, so this should cover most of your needs. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/Chapters/AboutInterfaceBuilder.html

Comment: I will definitely check that out.